# How can we place the value a variable in the middle of a sentence in python?

Tags: python-3.x, string, variables, error-handling, printing

For example, I  have an integer variable `usf = 5` and I want my output to be `It will be floor number 5 in US`. But when I write this as `print('It will be floor number', usf 'in US')`, I am getting syntax error.But when I write it as `print('US floor is', usf)` it works perfectly fine. What is the way to put variables in the middle of a sentence ?

Answer (score 1):

```
print('It will be floor number', usf, 'in US')
#                                   ^
```

You forgot a comma

Although if you have Python 3.6 or higher, use [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/):

```
print(f'It will be floor number {usf} in US')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [f-strings](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/formatted-string-literals-f-strings-python/) to make string formatting / interpolation way easier.

In your example, it would be `print(f"It will be floor number {usf} in US")`.

But also, your original code had a syntax error (most likely?) because you're forgetting another comma after 'usf' to separate the third part of your final string.

`print('It will be floor number', usf 'in US')`

VS

`print('It will be floor number', usf, 'in US')`